# Compact null self-adjoint 0perators

Tags: functional-analysis

The exercise says: " Find all compact self-adjoint operators $T: H \to H$ such that $T^(2017)=0 "$

Comment: Providing a litte bit more information and details would be a huge help...for example, what is $H$? Is it a vector space (over which field, real or complex numbers?), which additional structure do you consider ([Pre]-Hilbert space?), what have you tried in order to find a solution, where does the exercise come from (lecture notes, book)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $T $ is self-adjoint,  then  $||T^n||=||T||^n $ for all $n  $.

Conclusion?